# How to use dependency injected component in React (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on integrating React in to a TypeScript based framework. Unfortunately as soon as I want to inject components, the typings are not correct anymore.

I know that this is not the way a lot of people are using React, but instead of using higher order components we want to use dependency injection as it is in our opinion the better pattern.

I have tried to do the following

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export class Foo extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return (<div>Bar</div>);
    }
}

export class Foobar {
    constructor(private component: Foo) {}

    public render(): void {
        const Component = this.component;

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Component />, // <Foo /> works perfectly
            document.querySelector("#root")
        );
    }
}
```

But this does not work unfortunately. It errors with the following output

```
ERROR in src/app/test.tsx(17,14): error TS2604: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

If I try it like this

```
public render(): void {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(this.component, {}),
        document.querySelector("#root")
    );
}
```

It results in to the following

```
ERROR in src/app/test.tsx(15,33): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | StatelessComponent<{}> | ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
  Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
    Type 'Foo' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: {}, context?: any): Component<{}, any, any>'.
```

I am not really in favor of using `as any` in this scenario as I would love to be able to refactor `Foo` without having to manually check every instance if the props are passed down correctly.

I have heard from React.sfc but as far as I can tell it doesn't fix the problem I am facing.

Comment: Since you are not creating an object from `Foo` but passing the class itself, it seems that `ComponentClass<Props>` would be the type you want to use

Comment: *we want to use dependency injection as it is in our opinion the better pattern* -  it's possible that you approach it from the wrong side. React already uses dependency injection pattern via props and a context.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess that makes sense, good thing the dependency injector can work around with that :)

@estus contexts are not really dependency injection, its container aware pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have stated that your constructor takes an instance of `Foo`, denoted by the type `Foo` but you are actually passing using the class `Foo` denoted `typeof Foo`.

More specifically, change

```
export class Foobar {
  constructor(public component: Foo) {}
}
```

To

```
export class Foobar {
  constructor(public Component: typeof Foo) {}
}
```

By the way, higher order components are a dependency injection pattern. Dependency injection is nothing more than parameterization.

Answer (score 1):

`component` name is misleading because it's expected to be a constructor, and constructors are conventionally have pascal case names. It should be typed accordingly because `component: Foo` means that it's an instance of `Foo`.

It likely should be:

```
export class Foobar {
    constructor(private Component: typeof Foo) {}

    public render(): void {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <this.Component />
            document.querySelector("#root")
        );
    }
}
```

React already uses dependency injection pattern. Dependencies can be injected with props and context API, e.g.:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App Foo={FooImplementation}/>, ...);
```

Comment: This is only true when using JSX inside ReactDOM.render, which I am not in the second example and am using uppercase in the first example.

Comment: Not following this convention may result in mistakes, `component` name doesn't show the intention to get a constructor as a parameter. A developer sees `component: Foo` and thinks, 'ok, component is an instance of Foo, makes sense`, while it's Foo itself.

Comment: Yes I agree about the type, thats why I was asking. But the uppercase in this case doesn't make sense.

Comment: It makes sense for developers who got accustomed to this convention because `private Component: Foo` mistake can be spotted on sight, while `private component: Foo` seems ok at first sight.

Answer (score 0):

@Boy With Silver Wings gave the correct answer. I guess it feels a little bit wrong but I can totally understand why (JSX and such).